# Find and replace thousands of files with a complex regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I need to run a find and replace over thousands of files, matching on this expression

```
/typedef((?:\\w+|\\s+)+?)(\\w+);/
```

and replacing the match with this

```
#ifndef $2\ntypedef$1 $2\n#endif
```

The ultimate goal is to take a bunch of header files and make sure they don't have conflicting definitions. So it would replace lines like

```cpp
typedef unsigned char       __uint8_t;
```

with

```cpp
#ifndef __uint8_t
 typedef unsigned char      __uint8_t;
#endif
```

I have tried to use `awk` with `gensub` but I don't get the expect result

```bash
awk '{ 
print gensub(/typedef((?:\\w+|\\s+)+?)(\\w+);/, "#ifndef \2\ntypedef\1 \2\n#endif", "g", $0) 
}' myheader.h
```

If I try running the above command, the output prints unchanged. If I change the target from `$0` to `$1` I get

```
/*
*
*
*/

#ifdef
typedef
#else
typedef
#endif
typedef
typedef
typedef
typedef
typedef
typedef
typedef

typedef
typedef

/*
*
*
```

I'm not sure that `awk` is the right tool given the complexity of the expression. Is this something `awk` can handle and I'm just using it wrong, or is there a better approach?

Comment: should *all* `typedef` entries be converted or just some? if the latter, could you update the question to show some `typedef` entries that should *not* be converted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the significance of the regex (eg, should *all* `typedef` entries be converted?) ...

Setup:

```
$ cat myheader.h
typedef unsigned char       __uint8_t;
leave this line alone
typedef unsigned int       __whatever;
leave this line alone
typedef some other stuff char       __pick_me;
leave this line alone
```

Assuming *all* `typedef` entries are to be converted, one `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/typedef/ { $0= "ifndef " $NF ORS " " $0 ORS "endif" }
1
' myheader.h
```

This generates:

```
#ifndef __uint8_t;
 typedef unsigned char       __uint8_t;
#endif
leave this line alone
#ifndef __whatever;
 typedef unsigned int       __whatever;
#endif
leave this line alone
#ifndef __pick_me;
 typedef some other stuff char       __pick_me;
#endif
leave this line alone
```

Once the result is verified, and if using `GNU awk`, you can replace `awk` with `awk -i inplace` to overwrite the original file(s).

---

One idea for extending this answer to keep a re-run of the script from generating duplicate `#ifndef/#endif` pairs, and assuming the `#ifndef` and `typedef` are on consecutive lines:

```
awk '
/^#ifndef/       { defname=$NF; defline=FNR }
FNR==(defline+1) { defname=$NF }
/typedef/        { if (defname != $NF) $0= "#ifndef " $NF ORS " " $0 ORS "#endif" }
1
' myheader.h
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using GNU `awk`

```
$ awk '{match($0,/(typedef[^_]*(\w+);)/,a); print "#ifndef "a[2]"\n "a[1]"\n#endif"}' input_file
```

Or using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/typedef([^_]*)((\w+);)/#ifndef \3\n &\n#endif/' input_file
```

**Output**

```
#ifndef __uint8_t
 typedef unsigned char       __uint8_t;
#endif
```